# How to hide an icon if the link is empty

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

I want to hide an icon if the link is empty. Here is the `<a>` tag with `<i>` tag for Instagram. If the field from admin is empty, I want to hide it. I'm using the Laravel framework.

```
 <a href="https://instagram.com/{{ $model->instagram }}"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $followed_by }}</a>
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: what you mean empty? your link never will empty, cause there is part of link in any case

Comment: Using blade template engine: @if($model->instagram)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@if` blade directive:

```
@if ($model->instagram)
    <a href="https://instagram.com/{{ $model->instagram }}">
        <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $followed_by }}
    </a>
@endif
```

Depending on your Laravel version you might also have `@isset`/`@empty` directives available for you. You can read more about it in [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#if-statements).

Answer (score 1):

Use Blade `@if` Statement.

Simply Write like below code:-

```
@if(!empty($model->instagram))
<a href="https://instagram.com/{{ $model->instagram }}"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $followed_by }}</a>
@endIf
```

That's It.

You can read about more laravel Blade from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade)